# Variable on aspx page indicating that it is not declared

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015

I am busy doing maintenance on an old VB.Net/ASP.Net solution.
Quite a number of the .aspx pages reference variables on the code behind. While working, these all show up as errors, but the code does compile (making it not critical, but extremely annoying, and difficult to find actual errors).

I have tried `protected` and private `variables`.

I made a test page, to indicate the proble.

#### TestForm.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="TestForm.aspx.vb" Inherits="EGS.TestForm" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <%=message %>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

#### TestForm.aspx.vb

```
Public Class TestForm
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected message As String
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        message = "Hello!"
    End Sub
End Class
```

#### Error List

```
Error | BC30451 | 'message' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

#### Running it

```
Hello!
```

Is there a way to get Visual Studio (2015, if that makes a difference) to see these. They work just fine, like I said, it is just very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Use `public` modifier to declare the `message` variable

```
Public Class TestForm
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    public message As String
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        message = "Hello!"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Changing it to `public` gives the same error.

The result when running is exactly the same, it works.